# SQL Alchemy to Pandas - Code previously worked on 2.7 and not on 3.7

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, anaconda, pyodbc, python-3.7

I upgraded to python 3.7, and with that an updated version of SQL Alchemy. This code use to work fine to execute queries in py and set them into a dataframe via pandas. Now I'm running into a type error, I think the root cause is with the create_engine but I'm not too sure. I took a look at the documentation and it doesn't look like there was any changes in how the engine should be created.

```
path = '\\blah\\'
td = create_engine("mysql+pyodbc://<Username>:<Password>@DSN") # SQL Engine

def sqlDf(sql, engine):
    sql = open(sql,'r')
    sql = text(sql.read())
    return pd.read_sql(sql,engine) #SQL Function


df = sqlDf(path+'SQL.txt', td)
```

```
  File "C:\Users\44101\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Where previously I would have a dataframe saved to the kernal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A general hint: make sure you understand what is unicode and what is byte sting. Does `pd.read_sql` return `str` or `bytes`?

Comment: 9000, I believe unicode. From what I can tell the error happens when its connecting, so if I were to do td.raw_connection(), I would get the same error I posted above so something with the initiating the connection is happening.

Comment: @AbdullahSaid re: "From what I can tell the error happens when its connecting" - The error message says that the code is failing in the `do_execute` method of SQLAlchemy's `engine\default.py`, suggesting that the connection is successful but the `read_sql` is not. FWIW, I cannot reproduce your issue under CPython, so it may be an Anaconda issue. In any case, try omitting the `sql = text(sql.read())` statement which converts a `str` into a `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause` and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson, What version of sql alchemy are you running?
`
When I remove the text(), I receive another error.
ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='path\\sql.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
`

Comment: @AbdullahSaid - Sorry, I should have been clearer. By "omitting the ... text()" call I really meant `sql = sql.read()` instead of `sql = text(sql.read())`.

Comment: @GordThompson to your initial point I think it is something to do with anaconda, I used the pyodbc library instead and ran the query with the same logic just fine.
Thanks for the help guys